# Two columns updating each other on same table through a TRIGGER on SQL Server 2012

Tags: sql, triggers, sql-server-2012

Let me try to simplify the issue...

I have a table with two columns (A and B)

When A is updated, B will have to be updated (using A's new value to perform some calculation)
When B is updated, A will have to be updated (using B's new value to perform some calculation)

I'm trying to write a trigger to do perform this update, but I'm afraid that the condition will fall into a infinite loop, as every time A updates, it will try to update B; as b in being updated, it will try to update A and so on...

Any suggestion?

Thanks!

Comment: A flag in a third column? If `UPDATE` ColA from `EXTERNAL` then `FLAG=1`; If `UPDATE` ColB from `EXTERNAL` then `FLAG=2`; Then a process If 'FLAG=1 UPDATE ColB & SET FLAG=0' and if `FLAG=2 UPDATE ColA & SET FLAG=0` It's not pretty and there may be better ways, but it's the first thing that came to mind

Comment: @user3240704 I need to work this out without creating any more unnecessary information/columns. I didn't considerate this as an alternative as this is a work related task... I guess it would be fine at a personal/small project tho.
I really believe that might be some workaround using just the trigger itself, but I'm failing to find the solution.
Thanks for your input!

Comment: I use flags & timestamp columns in production environments when required. I'm interested in how to overcome this without a flag, this information will be valuable & the very best of luck

Comment: Thanks, I will update this once I have the solution... deadline is coming lol

Comment: You will find the same advice [here on SO](http://stackoverflow.com/a/430836/243373) in another similar question.

Comment: @TT. Thanks for the hint. That answer indeed helped me to solve the issue.

IF TRIGGER_NESTLEVEL() <= 1/*this update is not coming from some other trigger*/

Answer (score 0):

The [msdn documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189799.aspx) has a section about recursion. For your use case *indirect recursion* applies:

> **Recursive Triggers**
>   SQL Server also allows for recursive invocation of triggers when the RECURSIVE_TRIGGERS setting is enabled using ALTER
>   DATABASE. Recursive triggers enable the following types of recursion
>   to occur:
>
> **Indirect recursion**
>   With indirect recursion, an application updates table T1. This fires trigger TR1, updating table T2. In this scenario,
>   trigger T2 then fires and updates table T1.
>
> **Direct recursion** 
>   With direct recursion, the application updates table T1. This fires trigger TR1, updating table T1. Because table T1
>   was updated, trigger TR1 fires again, and so on.